# jQuery function doesn't work after after loading dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using below code. This is bootstrap 3 delete conformation message.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a.btnDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('div').data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});

$('#btnDelteYes').click(function () {
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    $('[data-id=' + id + ']').parent().remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    //ajax
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "delete.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
//$(".fav-count").html(html);
$("#output").html(html);
}
});
//ajax ends
});
});
```

This is the trigger element that I'm using

```
<div data-id="MYID"><a class="btnDelete" href="#">Delete</a></div>
```

And I'm using the same HTML element dynamically to trigger delete and it doesn't work.

Can someone point me the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use event delegation

```
$(document).on("click" , '#btnDelteYes' ,function () {
```

Pretty much: bind the click higher up to something that exists when the script is run, and when that something is clicked, tell it to pass the click event to the #btnDelteYes element instead

I cant understand what exactly you are doing on your code due to missing information, but the answer is: you should use event delegation on the dynamically inserted content

Comment: Awesome. It works with a bit of code tweak. I used `$(document).on("click" , '.btnDelete' ,function (e) {` instead of `$(document).on("click" , '#btnDelteYes' ,function () {` Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure :)
Please set the accepted answer for the sake of the future generations~

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
$('[data-id=MYID]').on('click','.btnDelteYes',function({
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).closest('div').data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});
```

here `<div data-id="MYID">` should be a hard coded html content and The idea is to delegate the events to that wrapper, instead of binding handlers directly on the dynamic elements.